# compareTo() method throwing "This method must return int" error despite returning int in method

Tags: java, return-value, return-type, compareto

I'm working on an assignment for my computer science course requiring me to implement a Comparable interface.

We haven't discussed the interface at any sort of length except just being told it compares two objects and returns less than, greater than and equal to, but literally that's about it, which is frustrating.

I intend to do more research on it, but for now I am finding I'm confused as to why my implementation of the compareTo() method isn't working.

Eclipse is giving me an error that compareTo() must return an `int`, but if you notice, I am returning an integer value. So what might be the issue?

```
public int compareTo(Task taskToCompare) {
    if(this.complete && taskToCompare.isComplete()) {
        if(this.priority == taskToCompare.getPriority()) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if(this.priority < taskToCompare.getPriority()){
            return -1;
        }
        else if(this.priority > taskToCompare.getPriority()) {
            return 1;
        }
    } else if(this.complete == true && taskToCompare.isComplete() == false) {
        return -1;
    } else if(this.complete == false && taskToCompare.isComplete() == true) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: what about when `this.complete == false && taskToCompare.isComplete() == false `

Comment: There is no return in the default case (if the if statements fall through).

Answer (score 9):

If the return type is `int`, you will have to return an `int` or `throw` an exception. Just exiting the method without a `return` will lead to a compiler error.

If you have a `if-else-if` condition, there may be a case where none of the blocks is called. You therefore should create an `else` statement with a `return`.

Also, the result of `isComplete()` and `taskToCompare.getPriority()` may change if you call the method multiple times. The compiler doesn't know if your logic prevents that.

For example, this is the case if `complete` is `false` and `isComplete()` also returns `false`. As before, the compiler doesn't know if your logic prevents that.

I think you want something like:

```
public int compareTo(Task taskToCompare) {
    if(this.complete && taskToCompare.isComplete()) {
        if(this.priority == taskToCompare.getPriority()) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if(this.priority < taskToCompare.getPriority()){
            return -1;
        }
        else{
            return 1;
        }
    } else if(this.complete == true && taskToCompare.isComplete() == false) {
        return -1;
    } else if(this.complete == false && taskToCompare.isComplete() == true) {
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh ok I see. Thank you. Shouldn't `this.complete && taskToCompare.isComplete()` take care of whether both tasks are complete or not?

Comment: No, if one of the tasks are incomplete, it not take care of it. If no task is completed, neither the `if` nor the `else-if` block will be invoked. Also, the `isComplete()` method may return different results if it is e.g. modifiedby another Thread between it is executed in the `if` and the `else if`.

Comment: I tried to implement:
`(this.complete == true && taskToCompare.isComplete() == true) || (this.complete == false && taskToCompare.isComplete() == false)`

Will (this.complete == false && taskToCompare.isComplete() == false) not implement to true?

Comment: also, again, thank you for helping and your time. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

What if `this.complete == false` and `taskToCompare.isComplete() == false`?

The compiler is complaining because you haven't covered every case.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for your input and making it clear.

Answer (score 1):

more compact version:

```
public int compareTo(Task taskToCompare) {
        int completeCompare = (this.complete == taskToCompare.complete) ? 0 : (this.complete  ? 1 : -1);
        if(completeCompare==0) {
            return  this.priority-taskToCompare.getPriority();
        }
        return completeCompare;
    }
```